# Moving files to a subfolder based on partial filename in VBA without using FSO

Tags: excel, vba

This code is run from a macro-enabled workbook. It checks if there is already any files in the same folder as the workbook which names start with "repositorio nóminas" and moves them to a subfolder.

It uses the method "Name _ As _" to move them, but the "* . *" argument does not seem to work in this context. How can I check for partial name while using the "Name _ As _" method?

```
Dim wb      As Workbook  
Dim path    As String

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook    
path = wb.path & "\"

If path & "\repositorio" & "*.*" = True Then            !!!Error 13 Type Mismatch!!!
    Name path & "\repositorio" & "*.*" As path & "backups\" & "\repositorio" & "*.*"
End If
```

For clarification, I got the idea of trying the "* . *" argument from this piece of code I had found in the past, where it uses "path" and the argument to find anything that exists in that path.

```
str = Dir(path & "*.*")

Do While str <> ""
    ctr = ctr + 1
    str = Dir
 Loop
```

Comment: Have a look to the documentation:  **Name arguments cannot include multiple-character (*) and single-character (?) wildcards.**.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement

Comment: Just use the output of the `Dir` and rename the files one by one within the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already written, you need to rename your files one by one. So the logic is: Loop over all files that matches the filename pattern and execute the `name` command.

To loop over all files in a folder, you can use the `Dir`-command (or use the FileSystemObject). The logic of the `Dir`-command is the following: You issue an initial `Dir` with a filename pattern (including the path). You will get the name of the first matching file as result. To get the next matching file, you issue another `Dir`-command, but without parameters`. As long as there are matching files,` Dir` will return the name. When there is no file left, it returns an empty string.

Note that the filename that is returned by `Dir` does not contain the path, only the file name.

So your code would look like that

```
Const FilenamePattern = "repositorio*.*"
Dim path as String, backupPath as String
path = wb.path & "\"
backupPath = path & "backups\"

Dim filename as string
filename = Dir(path & FilenamePattern)   ' Get first file
Do While filename <> ""
    ' Move the file to backup folder
    Name path & filename As backupPath & filename
    filename = Dir                       ' Get next file, if any
Loop
```

Comment: It is working flawlessly in the minimal example I made for this post's purposes, but when I use it with the main code it gives me Error 53 file not found on the Name As line.

Comment: Check content of filename, path and backupPath when this happens. Does the backup path exists? Else you need to create is first, either manually or by code (use the MkDir command). Also, this code fill fail when you use OneDrive

Comment: I was creating the backup path using mkdir, but due wrong use of If *backup path* = Empty to check if the backup folder was already created, the backup folder was never creating itself. Thank you for your patience and your code.